# Is a parse tree the same thing as bytecode?

Tags: perl

What exactly is the difference between bytecode and a parse tree, specifically the one used by Perl? Do they actually refer to the same concept, or is there a distinction?

I'm familiar with the concept of bytecode from Python and Java, but when reading about Perl, I've learned that it supposedly executes a parse tree (instead of bytecode) in its interpreter.

If there actually is a distinction, what are the reasons for Perl not using bytecode (or Python not using parse trees)? Is it mainly historical, or are there differences between the languages that necessitate a different compilation/execution model? Could Perl (with reasonable effort and execution performance) be implemented by using a bytecode interpreter?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What Perl uses is not a [parse tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parse_tree), at least not how Wikipedia defines it. It's an opcode tree.

```
>perl -MO=Concise -E"for (1..10) { say $i }"
g  <@> leave[1 ref] vKP/REFC ->(end)
1     <0> enter ->2
2     <;> nextstate(main 49 -e:1) v:%,{,2048 ->3
f     <2> leaveloop vK/2 ->g
7        <{> enteriter(next->c last->f redo->8) lKS/8 ->d
-           <0> ex-pushmark s ->3
-           <1> ex-list lK ->6
3              <0> pushmark s ->4
4              <$> const[IV 1] s ->5
5              <$> const[IV 10] s ->6
6           <#> gv[*_] s ->7
-        <1> null vK/1 ->f
e           <|> and(other->8) vK/1 ->f
d              <0> iter s ->e
-              <@> lineseq vK ->-
8                 <;> nextstate(main 47 -e:1) v:%,2048 ->9
b                 <@> say vK ->c
9                    <0> pushmark s ->a
-                    <1> ex-rv2sv sK/1 ->b
a                       <#> gvsv[*i] s ->b
c                 <0> unstack v ->d
-e syntax OK
```

Except, despite being called a tree, it's not really a tree. Notice the arrows? It's because it's actually a list-like graph of opcodes (like any other executable).

```
>perl -MO=Concise,-exec -E"for (1..10) { say $i }"
1  <0> enter
2  <;> nextstate(main 49 -e:1) v:%,{,2048
3  <0> pushmark s
4  <$> const[IV 1] s
5  <$> const[IV 10] s
6  <#> gv[*_] s
7  <{> enteriter(next->c last->f redo->8) lKS/8
d  <0> iter s
e  <|> and(other->8) vK/1
8      <;> nextstate(main 47 -e:1) v:%,2048
9      <0> pushmark s
a      <#> gvsv[*i] s
b      <@> say vK
c      <0> unstack v
           goto d
f  <2> leaveloop vK/2
g  <@> leave[1 ref] vKP/REFC
-e syntax OK
```

The difference between Perl's opcodes and Java's bytecodes is that Java's bytecodes are designed to be serialisable (stored in a file).

Comment: (Notice how the second output looks a *lot* like "the bytecode in raw and symbolic form, compiled for a stack-oriented virtual machine" later given by jjrv? Added are `nextstate` (which keep track of line numbers for warnings) and `pushmark` (which are needed for n-ary sub calls).)

Comment: If it's not a tree, then why do you start out saying it is?

Comment: @Rob Kennedy, It's easier to start from common ground: The OP called it a tree; it's commonly called a tree; Starts out as a tree. The word "tree" is often misapplied to graphs that aren't trees to the point of being acceptable. So it's a tree, but it's not a tree. I didn't want to start with something that would be construed as "everyone else is wrong". Because they're not really; they are using accepted terminology even though it's technically wrong. I've updated my post to clarify.

Comment: So the main difference is optimization for sequential instead of "random" access?

Comment: You can't jump to arbitrary addresses in either version. In both case, you might jump to an address that's not a opcode. Both model easily support `goto`, though. You can jump to any opcode just as easily in both models.

Comment: @jjrv, Yes, that's what I said. But this is what the OP is asking about. (fyi, With "MAD", you can actually save the original code in the opcode tree.)

Comment: @Rob Kennedy, Short answer: Because that's what people call it.

Comment: Definitions aside (ikegami is right, I'm just interested in Perl's specific implementation), I still don't quite get the "designed to be serialisable" part: Is perl's opcode "tree" actually just a series of opcodes like bytecode, but optimized for in-memory usage and without a clearly specified serialization format? Is it executed step by step, like "normal" bytecode, or by tree traversal? To me, your example looks a lot like the output of Python's disassembler. How big is the difference really, and what are the implications?

Comment: @Ixgr, Perl's opcodes are "structs" (simple objects), not short sequences of bytes, and they weren't designed to be converted to sequences of bytes. That they're not designed to be serialised means their format and the exact sequences can be specific to the virtual machine/interpreter executing these compiled ops. And they are. The <strike>implication</strike> result is that it's hard to save the compiled form of Perl code to disk.

Comment: @Ixgr, Re "Is it executed step by step, like "normal" bytecode, or by tree traversal?" hum, either the question makes no sense or the answer is obvious. The opcodes are executed in the order they should be executed in, and that order is not defined by a tree. The Perl [run loop](http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/blob/dc281e6088d189558b79a5121119b7196c8b3db0:/run.c#l41) is simply: `op = execute op;`.

Comment: Thanks, I think I get it now. I was confused by the description of Perl's execution of the opcode tree as "walking the tree". I thought that meant some kind of tree traversal, which obviously wouldn't work well with flow control/branching.

Comment: @Ixgr, What do you think "walk" means? It simply means "in turn". How can opcodes be executed anything but in turn? And we've already covered that it's not a tree. Trees can't have loops. Perl has loops.

Answer (score 7):

Parse tree is the tokens of a program, stored in a structure that shows their nesting (which arguments belong to which function calls, what statements are inside which loops etc.) while bytecode is the program code converted into a binary notation for quicker execution in a virtual machine. For example if you had the following code in an imaginary language:

```
loop i from 1 to 10 {
    print i
}
```

The parse tree might look for example like:

```
loop
    variable
        i
    integer
        1
    integer
        10
    block
        print
            variable
                i
```

Meanwhile the bytecode in raw and symbolic form, compiled for a stack-oriented virtual machine might look like:

```
0x01 0x01    PUSH 1
             START:
0x02         DUP
0x03         PRINT
0x05         INCREMENT
0x02         DUP
0x01 0x0a    PUSH 10
0x04         LESSTHAN
0x06 0xf9    JUMPCOND START
```

When compiling a program, you'd first need to parse the source code (usually producing a parse tree) and then transform it to bytecode. It can be easier to skip the second step and execute straight from the parse tree. Also, if the language syntax is very hairy (for example it allows modifying the code) then producing the bytecode gets more complicated. If there's an eval type function to execute any code, the whole compiler has to be distributed with the application to use the virtual machine for such code. Including only a parser is simpler.

In Perl 6, the next version of perl, the code is supposed to be compiled to bytecode and run on the Parrot virtual machine. It's expected to improve performance. Bytecode is fairly straightforward to compile further to the processor's native instructions (this is called a JIT compiler) to approach speed of compiled languages like C.

Comment: Perl 6 is a language standard (like C++) and does not define a particular implementation. Rakudo (Perl 6 on the Parrot VM) is just one possible implementation, and may or may not turn out to be the most popular one.  This is a significant change from Perl 5 and earlier, for which there's no language standard separate from the standard implementation.